# How can Update my display driver to OpenGL 3.3

Tags: steam

Can somebody help me with this? When open the game on steam ... appear a warning " update opengl to 3.3"

It’s my first question. I hope it’s all right.

---

```
   OS: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS x86_64 
   Host: MS-7693 3.0
```

Kernel: 4.15.0-24-generic 
Uptime: 14 mins 
Packages: 1928
Shell: bash 4.4.19
Resolution: 1920x1080
DE: Budgie
WM: Mutter(Budgie)
Theme: Pop [GTK2/3]
Icons: Pop [GTK2/3]
Terminal: tilix
CPU: AMD FX-6300 (6) @ 3.500GHz
GPU: AMD Radeon R7 370
Memory: 1479MiB / 15987MiB
OpenGL version string: 3.1 Mesa 18.1.1

Linux MS-7693 4.15.0-24-generic #26-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 13 08:44:47 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Curacao PRO [Radeon R7 370 / R9 270/370 OEM] (rev 81)